# Are Ember Models singleton?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Are the models in EmberJS singleton ?

I know that EmberJS Controllers are singleton, but not sure about models.

Also what are the ways by which we can create/access models in EmberJS (like one way is to use the "model" hook in the route class)

Any examples to explain would be great.

Comment: what is missing in the guides https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/ in your opinion ? will only answer specific questions, cause what you asked is explained in the guides

Answer (score 1):

Models are not singleton. Instances of model classes are called records.

You create records using store.createRecord. You access them using store.find and similar methods.

For more information, here is a link to the guides:
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/

Specifically regarding records:
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/#toc_records